# Replace value of a list in python

Tags: python

What I want to do is replace all the even numbers of a list with 0 for instance

`list = [1,2,3,4,5]` would be `list = [1,0,3,0,5]`

I thought about doing it this way

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in list:
  if i % 2 == 0:
  # then replace the even numbers with 0
```

the problem is that I cant figure out how to write the next line of code

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that if you start like this

```
for i in lst: 
    if i %2 == 0:
         # don't know the index of i
```

However, you can use `enumerate` to keep trace of the index - now it is easy

```
for idx, i in enumerate(lst):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        lst[idx] = 0
```

Usually it's simpler to use a list comprehension and replace the whole list with a new one.

You can test the lowest bit of each number using the bitwise and `&`

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
>>> L = [x if x & 1 else 0 for x in L]
>>> L
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
```

Depending on your CPU and the Python implementation, you may find this is faster (but less readable in my opinion):

```
[x * (x & 1) for x in L]
```

Comment: + one for the Best answer.

Comment: Thanks John and everyone, I am a beginner in python and this was really useful

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a list comprehension like so:

```
list = [x * (x%2) for x in list]
print list
```

Notice that x%2 can only result in 1 or 0. Hence, if the number is even, the result of multiplication is 0, and if it is odd, it is the number itself.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VUZT50785)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> def myfun(x):
    if x % 2 != 0:
        return x
    else:
        return 0


>>> list(map(myfun, my_list))
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
```

Comment: I like your unique as well as easy usage of map functions.For a newbie this suits the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_result = list()

for number in my_list:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        my_result.append(0)
    else:
        my_result.append(number)

print my_result
```

You can also use `list comprehensions`:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print [0 if x%2==0 else x for x in my_list]
```

**Output is the same for both examples:**

```
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
```

> It is important to highlight that `list` is a Python reserved word for its `list` data structure. That's why I assign the list a different name.

---

**Documentation:**

List comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @shree.pat18 I've modified my answer. I misunderstood what he needed. Thanks!

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal I've modified my answer. I misunderstood what he needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `List Comprehension and ternary method` :

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list1[:] = [a if a%2 != 0 else 0 for a in list1 ] #  [i if i % 2 == 1 else 0 for i in L]
print list1
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
```

**Notes:**

- By `list1[:]` I am not creating a new list I am adding to the already existing List
- What I have done in my LC is I checked if the value is `odd` then given the same value if not I have given `0`

Or for normal method

**Code1:**

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i,v in enumerate(list1):    
    if v%2==0:
        list1[i]=0
print list1
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
# List comp
[x if x % 2 else 0 for x in lst] # when x % 2 is 0 if returns false

# for-loop
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        lst[i] = 0

#Output
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
```